# Prove a limit for $g(x)$ with the definition of limit only

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

We have the function $g(x) = x^3+1$

Prove, **with the definition of limit only**, that the limit $L=9$ is indeed the limit of the function when  $x=2$.

I started with: $\lvert g(x) - L \rvert$ : $\lvert x^3+1-9 \rvert = \lvert x^3-8 \rvert = \lvert (x-2)(x^2+2x+4) \rvert < \epsilon $

From the definition of the limit we know: $ \rvert x-2 \lvert < \delta$,  so therefore: $\lvert (x-2)(x^2+2x+4) \rvert < \delta (x^2+2x+4) $

How do I proceed from here? do I need to find a condition for $ x^2+2x+4 $ ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $x^2+2x+4<19$ for $1<x<3$, hence we can take $\delta=\varepsilon/19$ for $\varepsilon<1$.

Comment: How did you know that $x2+2x+4 < 19 $ for $ 1 < x < 3 $ ?

Comment: @user1326293 It is increasing for positive $x$, and value in 3 is equal to 19.

Comment: This is not a good answer. You should specify that you are assuming a priori that $\delta < 1 $ so that you can have $|x-2| < 1 $. At the end, you take the min of $1$ and $\epsilon/19$.

Comment: @PedroArbizu It is a HINT! And OP needs some approximation from above. And 1/19 seems to be less than 1.

Comment: @PedroArbizu Big deal. Let's disregard it's much clearer than the other answer and give downvotes! \*facepalm\*

Comment: well, I think, without mentioning that you are choosing $\delta < 1$, this answer can be really confusing and not helpful for someone who is just learning the material. By the way, I donwvoted, but I will gladly upvote if the answer gets more clear.

Comment: @PedroArbizu If you assume, that a learner will not search arguments near to 2, but near the end of Solar System...

Answer (score 1):

$$|x^2+2x+4|=|x^2-4x+4+6x-12+12|=|(x-2)^2+6(x-2)+12| \leq |\delta^2+6\delta+12|$$

So for small $\delta$ you have (for example) $|x^2+2x+4|<13$